# Non supported claims in JWT implementation

Tags: php, android, jwt

I am implementing JWT in my application using php-jwt library from Firebase. I tried the example in the site and it is working fine.

```
$token = array(
"iss" => "http://example.org",
"aud" => "http://example.com",
"iat" => 1356999524,
"nbf" => 1357000000
);
```

However if I try to include other claims such as exp or sub, it throws UnexpectedValueException ('Wrong number of segments') exception. Has somebody encountered this issue ? Does the php-jwt library supports only the four claims shown in the example ? The code to receive the token in api is given below:

```
$headers = null;
if (isset($_SERVER['Authorization'])) {
$headers = trim($_SERVER["Authorization"]);
}
else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) { 
$headers = trim($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]);
} elseif (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
$requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();

$requestHeaders = array_combine(array_map('ucwords', array_keys($requestHeaders)), array_values($requestHeaders));
//print_r($requestHeaders);
if (isset($requestHeaders['Authorization'])) {
    $headers = trim($requestHeaders['Authorization']);
    }
  }
 if (!empty($headers)) {
    if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $headers, $matches)) {
        $jwt = $matches[1];
    }
}

$key = "example_key";
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
```

If the token is generated using the example in the site, then it works fine. If the token is generated using claims like:

```
$tokenId    = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(32));
$issuedAt   = time();
$notBefore  = $issuedAt + 3;             
$expire     = $notBefore + 3600;           

$token = array(
    "iss" => "http://example.com",
    "aud" => "http://example.com",
    "iat" => $issuedAt,
    "nbf" => $notBefore,
    "exp"    => $expire,
    "gate" => "kanchanjuri",
    "tokenId" => $tokenId
);
```

then the api call fails.

From app, the token is sent s follows:

```
      HttpURLConnection con = null;
      URL url = new URL(query);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + con.getResponseCode());
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: "wrong number of segements" just says that the decode function expected 3 segements in the token (header, payload and signature) separated by a `.` If there are more or less than 3 segments, you'll get the exception. Pls. edit your question and add more of your code

Comment: So the exception happens here: `$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));`, right?! Can you show us a token? As said before, the token doesn't seem to be complete. So let's see which part is missing.

Comment: I have found the issue. Actually after encoding code, i had immediately put the decoding code also for testing. I forgot to remove that code. So instead of the token, the decoded data got sent to the app. Still, can you have a look at my code and suggest improvements if any?